# How to load raw binary array data into Julia and display it?

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I would like to load a raw image data (such as the **.raw** ones from [http://eeweb.poly.edu/~yao/EL5123/SampleData.html](http://eeweb.poly.edu/%7Eyao/EL5123/SampleData.html)) into Julia and display them.
Basically, I am looking for a way to load file into Julia as `Array{xxx}` type.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code and along with the resulting plot:

```
using Plots, Images, HTTP
r = HTTP.request("GET", "http://eeweb.poly.edu/%7Eyao/EL5123/image/lena_gray.raw")
img = reshape(r.body, 512, 512)
v = rotr90(colorview(Gray, img./256));
Plots.plot(v)
savefig("lena.png")
```

[image]